Low contrast high resolution segmentation
So, I've been working on a segmentation project for about a year now. I've got a few methods which I'm applyiing to segment these images. Using saturation or luminance channels have been working fine for about 40-60% of the images. The big problem are the low contrast images.
Clothing on a white mannequin, white background. I need to remove both the mannequin and background.
Example Image
For the low contrast images, I've been experimenting with machine learning models for segmentation. I trained a custom model based on YoloV8 a few months ago, but I ran into a resolution problem. Yolo will do a fairly good segmentation of the images but in a 1024x1024px image. When I try to translate it to a full-res image (approximately 4000x6000px) it (obviously) get very pixelated.
So, it's kind of a more open question. I'm looking for strategies to segment this images.
My most recent almost-got-there idea was to use the segmentation from yolo for get a "ring" around the clothing and try segmenting only that area so that I can get the edges of the clothing, and with the help of OpenCV, find the contours and translate it to a binary mask.
Code-wise I'm at this point:
img  = cv.imread(img_path[0])
img_height, img_width, _ = img.shape

#RESIZE THE PARAMETERS FOR RESIZING THE IMG
if img_height > img_width:
    ratio = img_height/img_width
    rsz_height = CUSTOM_YOLO_INPUT_SIZE
    rsz_width = int(rsz_height/ratio)
else:
    ratio = img_width/img_height
    rsz_width = CUSTOM_YOLO_INPUT_SIZE
    rsz_height = int(rsz_width/ratio)

#RESIZE TO LONG EDGE CUSTOM_YOLO_INPUT_SIZE
rsz = cv.resize(img, (rsz_width,rsz_height), interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)

model = YOLO(CUSTOM_YOLO)

results = model.predict(
    rsz,
    max_det=2,
    verbose=False,
    retina_masks=True,
    imgsz=CUSTOM_YOLO_INPUT_SIZE,
    )

anotated = results[0].plot()

# CUSTOM FUNCTION TO GET YOLO OUTPUT AND TRANSLATE IT TO A BINARY MASK.
mask = getresults.extract_mask(results,rsz).astype("uint8")

mask = cv.resize(mask, (img_width, img_height))
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
img[:,:,3] = mask

kernel = kernel_c = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_CROSS,(100,100))
img[:,:,3] = first_gradient = cv.morphologyEx(img[:,:,3], cv.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
img[:,:,3] = cv.GaussianBlur(img[:,:,3],(15,15),0)

#### SOBEL
blurr = cv.GaussianBlur(img[:,:,:3],(5,5),0)
blurr = cv.cvtColor(blurr, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sobl = cv.bitwise_and(blurr,blurr,mask=img[:,:,3])
sobel_x = cv.Sobel(sobl, cv.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)

# Apply Sobel Y filter
sobel_y = cv.Sobel(sobl, cv.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)

# Calculate Sobel edge magnitude
sobel_magnitude = np.sqrt(sobel_x**2 + sobel_y**2)
sobel_magnitude = np.clip(sobel_magnitude,0,255)
sobel_subt = cv.inRange(sobel_magnitude,255,255)
sobel_magnitude = np.subtract(sobel_magnitude,sobel_subt)
sobel_magnitude = cv.inRange(sobel_magnitude,10,255)

Mask after the sobel filter - Current State
This image above is actually prety good in my opinion, but it still won't work with findcontours from OpenCV because the edges have a few gaps likes this:
Gaps in the edges
I've tried a few erosion/dilation combinations I wasn't able to close the gaps and I lost a lot of the accuracy in the edges. I know it's a trade-off but at this point I wasn't able to get good results.
So, at this point I'm looking for ways to improve on this or new strategy ideas. I'm trying to learn more about HQ-SAM to maybe get a better result, or possibly training a model based on HQ-SAM. Is there any segmentation model able to deal with higher quality images?

On the original provided, the problem is probably not low contrast, if you look at the red channel.  That might make it easier.  You may be able to just threshold the red channel to make a mask.

If instead you want to use the 1024x1024 yolo model on an image that is larger than that, you can cut the original into 1024x1024 squares and run the model on those pieces, then reconstruct the whole.  You may need to overlap the pieces somewhat to avoid edge effects.

@Pete The red channel is the one with least contrast, because pink and white will both have similarly high red levels. The green channel would probably be the one with the best contrast.

The biggest issue I often see in projects like these is that people will think of using a uniform background, but they will not think of uniformly lighting the background. You need to avoid shade on the background, so the subject has to be further away from the background, and has to be independently lighted (separate lights hitting the foreground and the background). The film industry has been doing green screen for many decades, why don't you look into how they do it, before you start implementing a project like this? Now you probably already have thousands of images...

@Pete Well, yes, it is true that one of the channels probably will have a higher contrast and I should have though of that. The thing is that it won't always be pink, the colors are almost every color possible. It seems a bit obvious now that you say it, but I should take a look at segmenting RGB channels. It might work very well. I just need to find some kind of threshold to determin when to use one of the RGB channels. About cutting and reconstructing the image, also sound like a good idea, I'll look into it.

@CrisLuengo I do know about chroma-keys. The problem for me is (1) lack of space to light a chroma set and (2) chroma would only remove the background unless the mannequin were also green (3) which is not an option due to minor refletions on the edges of the clothing and transparency on the fabrics that would destroy the color accuracy. I've been working on getting this background as uniform as possible but there are space constraints. Otherwise would be easier to just get a perfectly white bg, but that would still leave me with a mannequin to deal with. But I am aware of the uniformity issue

It is worth a shot, also Cris above was correct in that the red channel is likely to have the least contrast here, and the green channel is likely to have the most.  But in the general case you'd have to check all 3 and try to determine which has the best contrast.  There would also be much to gain by engineering the background on the setup to give you more contrast, but that may not be something you have control over, or the ship has sailed on that for images you'd already taken.

I'm not suggesting you use a green screen, it is not necessary. But look at how they illuminate the scene and set up the background to be as uniform as possible. Here's something you could do easily with a white background that is illuminated separately from the foreground: you can make the background darker for light colored foreground, and brighter for dark colored foreground. Space constraints might make this difficult though. Not sure what to suggest there other than having multiple different backgrounds, and picking the right one for each object you are photographing.
